# Dynamically execute string as code (eval) in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roslyn

Is there a way to execute a string as C# code in ASP.NET 5 with Roslyn?

In my case I want to dynamically convert a string to an linq expression.

For example:

```
obj.SomeFunc( "x => x.Username".ToLinqExpression() );
```

Or something like:

```
Eval("obj.SomeFunc(x => x.Username); ");
```

Is this possible in ASP.NET 5?

Comment: Look at the expression tree or dynamic linq.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using [Roslyn Scripting](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples). For example:

```
public class Globals
{
    public ObjType obj;
}

…

CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(
    "obj.SomeFunc(x => x.Username)", globals: new Globals { obj = obj });
```

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, you can try [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/releases/view/109593). I have used to generate sorting based on dynamic properties and it seems to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating a string requires compilation and an expression tree can easily be built using the Expression Class and compiling a delegate.
 Expression class is in System namespace.

Here are a couple of ways:

```
static Func<int, int, int, int, int> delInt = (i, j, k, l) => i + j * k - l;
int rslt1 = delInt(2, 3, 4, 5);  // evaluates lambda and returns int
static Func<int> delInt1 = () => 2 + 3 * 4 - 5;  // type the expression after => instead of assigning it to a string.
int rslt2 = delInt1();   // takes no parameters and returns int result.
```